# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'regex' while upgrading Django from 1.7.11 to 1.9.2

Tags: python, django, version

I'm working with the "third_party" example project of pybb (https://github.com/hovel/pybbm) [test folder] which works fine in django 1.7.11 but I've built the rest of my website in django 1.9.2. It gives me the following traceback in 1.9.2 and I'm not able to figure out whats wrong.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x032FB6B0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in
wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426,
 in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75,
in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 10, in c
heck_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 27, in c
heck_resolver
    warnings.extend(check_pattern_startswith_slash(pattern))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 63, in c
heck_pattern_startswith_slash
    regex_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'regex'
```

If it helps:
My urls.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

try:
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
except ImportError:
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import SignupFormWithCaptcha

admin.autodiscover()

from account.views import ChangePasswordView, SignupView, LoginView

urlpatterns = ['',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # aliases to match original django-registration urls
    url(r"^accounts/password/$", ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name="auth_password_change"),
    url(r"^accounts/signup/$", SignupView.as_view(form_class=SignupFormWithCaptcha), name="registration_register"),
    url(r"^accounts/login/$", LoginView.as_view(), name="auth_login"),

    url(r'^accounts/', include('account.urls')),
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('pybb.urls', namespace='pybb')),
]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please have a look. I'm relatively new to programming in general. Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try it. Remove empty string in urlpatterns.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # aliases to match original django-registration urls
    url(r"^accounts/password/$", ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name="auth_password_change"),
    url(r"^accounts/signup/$", SignupView.as_view(form_class=SignupFormWithCaptcha), name="registration_register"),
    url(r"^accounts/login/$", LoginView.as_view(), name="auth_login"),

    url(r'^accounts/', include('account.urls')),
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('pybb.urls', namespace='pybb')),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!! :)
However, I'm still running into errors. Currently, this one: RuntimeError: Model class social.apps.django_app.default.models.UserSocialAuth doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS. 
Any advice?

Comment: Actually, solved it by including "'social.apps.django_app'" in INSTALLED_APPS. Now, you must be thinking I'm a total noob. Possible- but I think I'm progressing fast for my situation. But I still want to get to a 6,085 reputation on StackOF. Dayum thats huge. But I dont know how I might be able to do that- all my questions plateau quickly and barely get votes. :-/ Do the folks who get 100 or even 1000+ votes, have corporate accounts or something?